# UWP XAML ImageBrush.imageSource from networkshare

Tags: image, xaml, uwp

i edited my question:

i have a stack panel with buttons from array.
now I want to set the Button Background from networkshare images.

here ist my source code:

XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="App4.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App4"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" Height="1205.722" Width="2045.722">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <StackPanel x:Name="sp" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="1070" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" Padding="0" CornerRadius="10" RequestedTheme="Light" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
            <MenuFlyout/>
        </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Behind Code:

```
private void onLoad()
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < imgNames.Length; ++i)
        {
            ImageBrush brush1 = new ImageBrush();
            brush1.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///assets/" + imgNames[i]));
            Button button = new Button()
            {
                Content = string.Format(""),
            Tag = i
            };
            button.Width = 100;
            button.Height = 100;
            button.Background = brush1;
            button.Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0);


            button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button_Click);   

            this.sp.Children.Add(button);


        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You are using Image brush not image ?????

Comment: sorry I updated my question

Comment: i created a sample for you which sow how to change button background from network location i will share a link shortly.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For loading image from network source you need to use these capabilities in your app

```
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
  <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
  <uap:Capability Name="enterpriseAuthentication" />
</Capabilities>
```

and your image

```
<Image Name="YourImageElementName" />
```

and loading image in code behind

```
StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"\\Your Image Full Path e.g user\folder\subfolder");
StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("ImageName.jpg");
using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
{
    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.SetSource(stream);
    YourImageElementName.Source = bitmap;
}
```

**Github sample** i created for this https://github.com/shubdragon/LoadNetworkImageRepo

**Points need to noted**

1) You need to set your network location in code and image name with required extension.

2) must share that location to homegroup.

3) Note code behind in different pages and Package.appxmanifes (view it as code in xml editor)

Comment: Thanks got it! You‘re the best!